# Bootstrap Dropdown appears behind other elements

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4

I have a template that mix bootstrap accordion and dropdown, the problem is that dropdown appears behind the next question card or what is the same, inside your card and is not seen.

template.html:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <!-- Acordion -->
  <div class="accordion" id="dlns_faqs_acordion">
    {% for element in elements %}
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header dlns_faqs_acordion_heading" id="dlns_faqs_acordion_heading_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dlns_faqs_acordion_content_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="dlns_faqs_acordion_content_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
              {{ element.question }}
            </button>
          </h2>
          <!-- Options -->
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn dlns_elements_button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right text-center" arial-labelledby="option_button">
              ...
              <a>...</a>
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dlns_faqs_acordion_content_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" class="dlns_faqs_acordion_content collapse" aria-labelledby="dlns_faqs_acordion_heading_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" data-parent="#dlns_faqs_acordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            {{ element.answer }}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

style.css:

```
.dlns_faqs_acordion {
  border: none;
}

.dlns_faqs_acordion_heading {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.dlns_faqs_acordion_heading button {
  color: var(--dlns_color_primary) !important;
}

.dlns_faqs_acordion_heading button.collapsed {
  color: black !important;
}

.dlns_faqs_acordion_heading button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dlns_faqs_acordion_content {
  color: var(--dlns_color_tertiary);
}
```

Here there are some images with the problem:

[image]
[image]

And the Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/albertosanmartinmartinez/o287rysk/12/

Anybody cloud help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do u try using `z-index` to the dropdown ?

Comment: yes, but doesn't work.

Comment: it will be easier to help u if u add working code (compile code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not create a fiddle or plnkr, i can only provide some suggestions:

- Manually adjust the dropdown-menu box `z-index` to a very big value to see if it works.
- Check the container who cut the dropdown-menu, to ensure the `overflow` property is set to visible.

**Update**:

```
.card {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65fq347r/

Comment: Updated with fiddle

Comment: @AlbertoSanmartinMartinez Updated the answer with a fiddle.

Comment: overflow: visible not fixed the problem.

Comment: @AlbertoSanmartinMartinez have you check the fiddle i pasted? It works perfectly, you need add !important; to override the existing overflow

Comment: Have you ever checked the jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry so much, my mistake.

Comment: It's ok. Could revert the vote down by clicking up arrow?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone ending up here through google:
For me the culprit was an `opacity` property on one of the parent divs.